# How to integrate a month criteria in filter function in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

Table 1:

[image: Table 1]

Table 2:

[image: Table 2]

This was my original query that's in Table 2, taken from Table 1.

`=SUMIFS(C:C,D:D,"Necessities Others",B:B,"Visa",A:A,">="& DATE(Year(today()),1,1),A:A,"<="& EOMONTH(DATE(year(today()),1,1),0))`

It would add everything in the column **Payment** (C:C) that had the **Necessities** category (D:D) that uses the **Visa** account (B:B), in a certain month (A:A) -- January in the example above.

But I switched to using the **filter** function because I wanted multiple criteria for Necessities

`=SUM(FILTER(C:C,REGEXMATCH(D:D,"Health/Medicine|Education|Necessities Others"),B:B="Visa",...`

but I don't know how to incorporate my previous query on month to this format. Help?

Comment: Maybe it is off topic, but why don't you use pivot table?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that since I'm new to spreadsheets. Unfortunately the entire spreadsheet is almost done and I wouldn't want to redo the entire thing. It would be helpful in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C:C, 
 REGEXMATCH(D:D, "Health/Medicine|Education|Necessities Others"), 
 B:B="Visa",
 A:A>=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1),
 A:A<=EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1), 0)))
```

Comment: Oh it does work. I did try that before but it kept on returning #N/A and I realized just now that its just because there were nothing that matched the criteria. My only issue now is that it doesnt return 0 when nothing matches. But thanks.

Comment: @Laine you can wrap it into `=IFERROR(sum_fx_here, 0)`